# Assigning to an element via iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I thought we can assign a new value to the elemnt of a container through its ***non-const*** iterator. So I tried that:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>

typedef std::set<int>::iterator it;

std::set<int> set_int;

int main()
{ 
    set_int.insert(1);
    it i = set_int.begin();
    *i = 11;  //error: assignment of read-only location
}
```

and failed. Why did I fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard [N4431](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf) *§23.2.4/6 Associative containers [associative.reqmts]* (**emphasis mine**):

`iterator` of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category. **For associative containers where the value type is the same as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators.** It is
unspecified whether or not iterator and const_iterator are the same type. [ Note: `iterator` and `const_-iterator` have identical semantics in this case, and `iterator` is convertible to `const_iterator`. Users can avoid violating the One Definition Rule by always using `const_iterator` in their function parameter lists.— end note ].

`std::set` is an associative container where its value type is the same as the key type, thus, `std::set<T>::iterator` is a constant iterator. Consequently, the failure you're getting is well justified.

Comment: Did't know that the rule also applies to map, multiset, multimap, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A `set` doesn't really have a non-`const` iterator, because its elements are immutable. If you think about it, suppose you change the key through an iterator. Why would the poor set move the node around to keep tree invariants and so forth?

For a more detailed & nuanced discussion, see [this piece](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Cuj/01.SetIterators/SetIterators.html) by Angelika Langer.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` keeps an order of elements internally. It is basically a  red black tree binary implementation and using std::less<> as its default comparator. So if I modify your example slightly as follows:

```
    typedef std::set<int>::iterator it;
    std::set<int> set_int;
    set_int.insert(1);
    set_int.insert(6); //I added 
    it i = set_int.begin(); //error: assignment of read-only location
    *i = 11;
```

`11` cant fit in first iterator position of the your std::set container, since it violate its order.

So it is obvious that we can't update an element using iterator dereference of an `std::set`. Compiler do not allow it, you will get compiler error.